# How to parse JSON response containing Multiple list data using Retrofit?

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb, retrofit2, gson

I am new to android ,I want to retrieve this JSON from Amazon DynamoDB , I have used a retrofit2 to retrieve this data from Amazon DynamoDB .Please guide me to get the Output.JSON file contain multiple ArrayList .

```
{
  "configContent": {
    "addressTypes": [
      "Home",
      "Work"
    ],
    "firstTimeInterval": 1,
    "gender": [
      "Male",
      "Female",
      "Trans-Female",
      "Bi-Gender",
      "Non-Binary",
      "Gender nonconfirming",
      "Undisclosed",
      "Rather not say"
    ],
    "languages": [
      "English",
      "Spanish",
      "Marathi",
      "Hindi",
      "Bengali",
      "French",
      "Arabic",
      "German",
      "Italian",
      "Dutch",
      "Japanese",
      "Russia",
      "Korean"
    ],
    "mapResetTimeInterval": 30,
    "meetingTrackableTime": 3600,
    "meetmeSearchContactTimeInterval": 2,
    "numberOfParticipants": 8,
    "profileToastDelatimebysix": 6,
    "profileToastDelayTime": 4,
    "secondTimeInterval": 2,
    "signupToastdelatimebysix": 6,
    "signupToastDelayMedium": 5,
    "signupToastDelayTime": 4,
    "syncToastMaxTimeInterval": 300,
    "syncToastThirdTimeInterval": 180,
    "toastDelayTimeForPulse": 3,
    "trackingOptions": [
      {
        "isDeleted": 0,
        "isTimeRequired": 1,
        "optionName": "Before the meet",
        "trackingTime": [
          5,
          10,
          15
        ]
      },
      {
        "isDeleted": 0,
        "isTimeRequired": 1,
        "optionName": "After the meet",
        "trackingTime": [
          5,
          10,
          15
        ]
      },
      {
        "isDeleted": 0,
        "isTimeRequired": 0,
        "optionName": "At the start",
        "trackingTime": []
      },
      {
        "isDeleted": 0,
        "isTimeRequired": 0,
        "optionName": "Never",
        "trackingTime": []
      }
    ],
    "transportModes": [
      "Walking",
      "Driving"
    ]
  },
  "createdDate": "2018-04-17T10:53:50.721Z",
  "id": "bb52dc0f-29d0-4079-99c7-a07c8045a829",
  "moduleName": "MeetMe"
}
```

This is Interface

```
public interface Api {

    String BASE_URL = "https://sz3i35gurk.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/";

    @GET("meetmeconfigurations")
    Call<Hero> getHeroes();
```

POJO CLASS

Hero.class

```
public class Hero  {

    private String id;

    private ConfigContent configContent;

    private String moduleName;

    private String createdDate;
}
```

ConfigContent.class

```
public class ConfigContent {
    private String mapResetTimeInterval;

    private String signupToastdelatimebysix;

    private String toastDelayTimeForPulse;

    private String profileToastDelatimebysix;

    private TrackingOptions[] trackingOptions;

    private String firstTimeInterval;

    private String signupToastDelayTime;

    private String meetingTrackableTime;

    private String[] addressTypes;

    private String[] languages;

    private String signupToastDelayMedium;

    private String numberOfParticipants;

    private String syncToastMaxTimeInterval;

    private String syncToastThirdTimeInterval;

    private String profileToastDelayTime;

    private String[] gender;

    private String meetmeSearchContactTimeInterval;

    private String[] transportModes;

    private String secondTimeInterval;

}
```

TrackingOption.class

```
public class TrackingOptions {
    private String optionName;

    private String isTimeRequired;

    private String isDeleted;

    private String[] trackingTime;
}
```

MainActivity file

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
                .build();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<Hero> call = api.getHeroes();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Hero>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Hero> call, Response<Hero> response) {
                Hero heroList =  response.body();
                data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(heroList));
                Log.d("Data","Data recevied:"+data);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Hero> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("error message","error message"+t);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

So when I run the program I get the null value  please help to solve the issue

Comment: your api not giving repsonse ?

Comment: I am not getting any response.

Comment: Share your project if possible

Comment: ok I wil share you drive link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=10aI7pbN2qJMH-t_wVi7FVKYEyNkyNdK0

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your all POJO classes with get set methods.For an example i've completed `ConfigContent` Class for you.

```
public class ConfigContent {

        @SerializedName("addressTypes")
        @Expose
        private List<String> addressTypes = null;
        @SerializedName("firstTimeInterval")
        @Expose
        private Integer firstTimeInterval;
        @SerializedName("gender")
        @Expose
        private List<String> gender = null;
        @SerializedName("languages")
        @Expose
        private List<String> languages = null;
        @SerializedName("mapResetTimeInterval")
        @Expose
        private Integer mapResetTimeInterval;
        @SerializedName("meetingTrackableTime")
        @Expose
        private Integer meetingTrackableTime;
        @SerializedName("meetmeSearchContactTimeInterval")
        @Expose
        private Integer meetmeSearchContactTimeInterval;
        @SerializedName("numberOfParticipants")
        @Expose
        private Integer numberOfParticipants;
        @SerializedName("profileToastDelatimebysix")
        @Expose
        private Integer profileToastDelatimebysix;
        @SerializedName("profileToastDelayTime")
        @Expose
        private Integer profileToastDelayTime;
        @SerializedName("secondTimeInterval")
        @Expose
        private Integer secondTimeInterval;
        @SerializedName("signupToastdelatimebysix")
        @Expose
        private Integer signupToastdelatimebysix;
        @SerializedName("signupToastDelayMedium")
        @Expose
        private Integer signupToastDelayMedium;
        @SerializedName("signupToastDelayTime")
        @Expose
        private Integer signupToastDelayTime;
        @SerializedName("syncToastMaxTimeInterval")
        @Expose
        private Integer syncToastMaxTimeInterval;
        @SerializedName("syncToastThirdTimeInterval")
        @Expose
        private Integer syncToastThirdTimeInterval;
        @SerializedName("toastDelayTimeForPulse")
        @Expose
        private Integer toastDelayTimeForPulse;
        @SerializedName("trackingOptions")
        @Expose
        private List<TrackingOption> trackingOptions = null;
        @SerializedName("transportModes")
        @Expose
        private List<String> transportModes = null;

        public List<String> getAddressTypes() {
        return addressTypes;
        }

        public void setAddressTypes(List<String> addressTypes) {
        this.addressTypes = addressTypes;
        }

        public Integer getFirstTimeInterval() {
        return firstTimeInterval;
        }

        public void setFirstTimeInterval(Integer firstTimeInterval) {
        this.firstTimeInterval = firstTimeInterval;
        }

        public List<String> getGender() {
        return gender;
        }

        public void setGender(List<String> gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
        }

        public List<String> getLanguages() {
        return languages;
        }

        public void setLanguages(List<String> languages) {
        this.languages = languages;
        }

        public Integer getMapResetTimeInterval() {
        return mapResetTimeInterval;
        }

        public void setMapResetTimeInterval(Integer mapResetTimeInterval) {
        this.mapResetTimeInterval = mapResetTimeInterval;
        }

        public Integer getMeetingTrackableTime() {
        return meetingTrackableTime;
        }

        public void setMeetingTrackableTime(Integer meetingTrackableTime) {
        this.meetingTrackableTime = meetingTrackableTime;
        }

        public Integer getMeetmeSearchContactTimeInterval() {
        return meetmeSearchContactTimeInterval;
        }

        public void setMeetmeSearchContactTimeInterval(Integer meetmeSearchContactTimeInterval) {
        this.meetmeSearchContactTimeInterval = meetmeSearchContactTimeInterval;
        }

        public Integer getNumberOfParticipants() {
        return numberOfParticipants;
        }

        public void setNumberOfParticipants(Integer numberOfParticipants) {
        this.numberOfParticipants = numberOfParticipants;
        }

        public Integer getProfileToastDelatimebysix() {
        return profileToastDelatimebysix;
        }

        public void setProfileToastDelatimebysix(Integer profileToastDelatimebysix) {
        this.profileToastDelatimebysix = profileToastDelatimebysix;
        }

        public Integer getProfileToastDelayTime() {
        return profileToastDelayTime;
        }

        public void setProfileToastDelayTime(Integer profileToastDelayTime) {
        this.profileToastDelayTime = profileToastDelayTime;
        }

        public Integer getSecondTimeInterval() {
        return secondTimeInterval;
        }

        public void setSecondTimeInterval(Integer secondTimeInterval) {
        this.secondTimeInterval = secondTimeInterval;
        }

        public Integer getSignupToastdelatimebysix() {
        return signupToastdelatimebysix;
        }

        public void setSignupToastdelatimebysix(Integer signupToastdelatimebysix) {
        this.signupToastdelatimebysix = signupToastdelatimebysix;
        }

        public Integer getSignupToastDelayMedium() {
        return signupToastDelayMedium;
        }

        public void setSignupToastDelayMedium(Integer signupToastDelayMedium) {
        this.signupToastDelayMedium = signupToastDelayMedium;
        }

        public Integer getSignupToastDelayTime() {
        return signupToastDelayTime;
        }

        public void setSignupToastDelayTime(Integer signupToastDelayTime) {
        this.signupToastDelayTime = signupToastDelayTime;
        }

        public Integer getSyncToastMaxTimeInterval() {
        return syncToastMaxTimeInterval;
        }

        public void setSyncToastMaxTimeInterval(Integer syncToastMaxTimeInterval) {
        this.syncToastMaxTimeInterval = syncToastMaxTimeInterval;
        }

        public Integer getSyncToastThirdTimeInterval() {
        return syncToastThirdTimeInterval;
        }

        public void setSyncToastThirdTimeInterval(Integer syncToastThirdTimeInterval) {
        this.syncToastThirdTimeInterval = syncToastThirdTimeInterval;
        }

        public Integer getToastDelayTimeForPulse() {
        return toastDelayTimeForPulse;
        }

        public void setToastDelayTimeForPulse(Integer toastDelayTimeForPulse) {
        this.toastDelayTimeForPulse = toastDelayTimeForPulse;
        }

        public List<TrackingOption> getTrackingOptions() {
        return trackingOptions;
        }

        public void setTrackingOptions(List<TrackingOption> trackingOptions) {
        this.trackingOptions = trackingOptions;
        }

        public List<String> getTransportModes() {
        return transportModes;
        }

        public void setTransportModes(List<String> transportModes) {
        this.transportModes = transportModes;
        }

}
```

Comment: still you get null value?

Comment: yes, I have turned off the authorization on api gateway

Comment: Not able to get the response

Comment: Should i use Okhttp for aws authentication and content type, region?

Comment: please check your api through POSTMAN. i don't know about aws authentication.please google it .Every service provider have their own way to configure and authenticate their api

Comment: what is that response?

Comment: i'll get back to you after checking your project.

Comment: `OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder(); httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
  @Override   public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
 Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().
              addHeader("content-type", "application/json")                 .addHeader("idtoken","eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJGRTU3NjM0NzMyOTMyNiJ9.NjDE0QDyscvr1I7IP9AHZ5_Cfd9xPQBKoynMz2SYUXYKTfbYwk3KmIU_eyfKDd258QastD1s3KeVlQCYOTJ54Q")
                        .build();
return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });`

Comment: Have you got the solutions?

Comment: I got the solution @MD.Zakir Hossain but I need your help How to store the response so we can use the value